# Чтение файла, начиная с определенного места

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
def readFromFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r+b') as file:
         res = file.read(100)

    return res
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы можно было, считав первые 100 символов, пропустить следующие 100 и считать оставшиеся символы? Насколько я понимаю `file.read()` не поддерживает `offset`?

Comment: `file.seek(file.tell() + 100); rest = file.read()` - надо бы еще добавить проверку на выход за конец файла?

Comment: @m9_psy вы с текстовым режимом путаете. Для rb единицы являются байтами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы можно было, считав первые 100 символов, пропустить следующие 100 и считать оставшиеся символы?

```
first100 = file.read(100)
file.read(100)  # skip
rest = file.read()
```

Альтернативно, особенно если больше 100 байт нужно пропустить:

```
first100 = file.read(100)
file.seek(100, os.SEEK_CUR)  # skip
rest = file.read()
```